# Are there any guidelines to structuring a JSON message?

Tags: javascript, json

Are there any guidelines specific to design JSON objects so that I can exchange information between server and browser?

Usecases like setting up a cookie in browser containing actual data with hash values. Any JSON exchanged between browser and server use these hashes to generate proper data using those stored hashes?

-Lalith

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to read the original spec at http://www.json.org/.